# Add 'go to page' functionality to material pagination in angular

Tags: angular, angular-material

I need to add a 'jump to' functionality to material pagination. it doesn't have built-in method for that so I need to add it manually.

at the moment I have this code:

```
<mat-paginator [length]="pageLength"
                       [pageSize]="10"
                       [pageSizeOptions]="pageLength | checkPageLength"
                       [showFirstLastButtons]="true">
        </mat-paginator>
```

and it shows: my current pagination
and I need it to have a textbox and a 'go' button for jumping to a specific page since I have many pages.

Comment: Request you to share the Stackblitz

Answer (score 17):

I found a piece of code from [here](https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/7615#issuecomment-358620095) which is working fine for me:

```
this.paginator.pageIndex = pageNumber;

this.paginator.page.next({      
     pageIndex: pageNumber,
     pageSize: this.paginator.pageSize,
     length: this.paginator.length
});
```

[`Working_Example`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-paginator)

Comment: the working example is broken, otherwise it works.

Answer (score 8):

I have created a `mat-paginator-goto` component over `mat-paginator`, this works same  as original `mat-paginator` but also has option of **goTo/jumpTo** specific page.

The list of available pages for **goTo** have been calculated based on `length` and `pageSize`.

To Integrate in your `angular/material` project follow below steps

**Step 1:** Goto [mat-paginator-with-goto (Stackblitz)](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-paginator-with-goto)

**Step 2:** Copy folder(`mat-paginator-goto`) and paste into you project

**Step 3:** Import in your `module`

```
import { MatPaginatorGotoComponent } from './mat-paginator-goto/mat-paginator-goto.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [ ...MatPaginatorGotoComponent ],
})
```

**Step 4:** Use it same as original `mat-paginator`

```
<mat-paginator-goto [length]="100" [pageSize]="10" [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 25, 100]"
        (page)="paginationChange($event)"></mat-paginator-goto>
```

**Note: Update import paths and styles accordingly**

**Note: You may face application freezing issue if the total page count is huge, I ended up replacing `mat select` with `mat input`**

Comment: Very helpful, but I had to fix two things: use `Math.ceil(this.length / this.pageSize)` to compute the correct number of pages, and also add `this.paginator.page.next({...})` in the `goToChange` method to update MatTableDataSource (only updated the paginator without this line).

Comment: [Here is an updated stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-paginator-with-goto-hgjasq?file=src/app/app.component.html) with the fix I discussed earlier.

Comment: Thanks @Carrm, Stackblitz updated and also added note (See above).

Comment: @SameerKhan how did you bind the mag-paginator-goto to the data source. Though I could include this code but the pager is not getting displayed.

Comment: @SameerKhan never mind, I got it sorted with adding a property in my component 
` @ViewChild('basecomp', {static: true}) jumpingPaginator: MatPaginatorGotoComponent;` and then binding the property `paginator` on the instance of `MatTableDataSource.`  to `this.jumpingPaginator.paginator`. 
This was possible since, you had the `MatPaginator` in the `paginator` property in your component.

Answer (score 1):

In your html file

```
<mat-form-field>
   <input matInput [(ngModel)]="goToPage">
</mat-form-field>
<button (click)="updateGoToPage()">Go</button>
```

And in your ts file

```
@ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;

goToPage = null;
updateGoToPage() {

    this.paginator.pageIndex = this.goToPage - 1;
  }
```

May be this will help.

Comment: He is asking for Go to Page that is User can enter any page number and click to redirect to that page